# Bootstrap carousel indicators. Change indicator class depending on if it's active or not

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, indicator

Here is the code of the Bootstrap indicators:

```
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```

What I want is to change li's class to `prev` and `next` depending on which indicator is clicked, e.g.:

```
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="1" class="next"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="2" class="next"></li>
```

or

```
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="0" class="prev"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-showcase" data-slide-to="2" class="next"></li>
```

or

Answer (score 0):

var indicators = $("ol.carousel-indicators li");

$(indicators).click(function () {

```
if ($(indicators).hasClass("active")) {

    if ($(this).attr("data-slide-to") == 0) {

        $("#two").removeClass("prev");

        $("#three").removeClass("prev");

        $("#two").removeClass("active");

        $("#three").removeClass("active");

        $("#one").addClass("active");

        $("#two").addClass("next");

        $("#three").addClass("next");

    } if ($(this).attr("data-slide-to") == 1) {

        $("#one").removeClass("next");

        $("#three").removeClass("prev");

        $("#one").removeClass("active");

        $("#three").removeClass("active");

        $("#one").addClass("prev");

        $("#two").addClass("active");

        $("#three").addClass("next");

    } if ($(this).attr("data-slide-to") == 2) {

        $("#one,#two").removeClass("next");

        $("#two").removeClass("next");

        $("#one").removeClass("active");

        $("#two").removeClass("active");

        $("#one").addClass("prev");

        $("#two").addClass("prev");

        $("#three").addClass("active");

    }

}
```

});

html:

Hi Try this this may help u out..
and please copy the css styles from here: http://jsfiddle.net/rCH3K/1/
and this fiddle is not working but working in local tested in ie/chrome/ffox.

mark as answered if it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).hasClass('active')) {
    //change here
}
```